# Honda Prelude: digital fuel and temp gauges dimming and brightening repeatedly

Tags: electrical, honda, gauges

I have noticed an annoying issue on my '94 (4th gen) Honda prelude. The digital petrol and temperature gauges appear very faint when starting the car. After about 5 mins they brighten again, only to fade once more a few moments later. This repeats throughout driving.

I've checked the instrument light dimming switch, and its fine (on full).

Would anyone know what could be causing this?

We've had a bit of rain here lately, could that be affecting it?

Comment: Is there an auto-dimmer turned on somewhere?

Comment: @hillsons I dont think so. It also dims right down to the point were it is only barely visible.

Comment: How do other lights behave? Is it possible they all dim and brighten in unison? Does the effect occur on idle and/or if you press accelerator pedal?

Comment: @KromStern All the other lights are fine. The effect doesnt seem to be related with the engine speed, though it does seem to have a 'warm up period' of about 5mins where it is completely blank.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like just worn out electrical components. My experience with this is the digital dashes in the 80s Nissan 300ZXs. The flux/residue left on the circuit boards corrodes over time and the corrosion eventually shorts some connections, causing a multitude of symptoms.